# Is this really the image of Sauron?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

I was browsing the internet and saw this image that is claimed to show Sauron in his original "Maiar" form.

[image: Sauron]

I wonder, is this really Sauron or is it just an internet rumour?

The image had this comment:

> The Maiar form was supposed to change into the Sauron we see in the
>   beginning of the first movie, so Aragon could fight Sauron. But then
>   they changed it to him fighting the troll. The light this form emits
>   was changed to the light of the Eye of Sauron looking at Aragon.

Comment: *"I was browsing the internet.."*  The internet is a big place.  Care to narrow it down with an URL?

Comment: @AndrewThompson [9gag](http://9gag.com/gag/aD0KR47/this-is-sauron-in-his-pure-maia-form-deleted-scene-from-lotr) T_T

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "really".

That image was made for Peter Jackson's movies, and has little basis in Tolkien's own writings. Tolkien himself never described Sauron, in either his "beautiful form" or his "evil form" in any great detail, so you're never going to get any definitive or canonical representation.

The most detail we have is the following from *The Council of Elrond*:

> ...in that time he was not yet evil to behold...

And from *Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*:

> ...for long if he willed he could still appear noble and beautiful, so as to deceive all but the most wary.

And other similarly brief descriptions elsewhere.

Based on these, that image is as good an interpretation as any, but an interpretation is all it can ever be.

Having said all of that, it's also important to note that (before he lost the power to do so at the end of the Second Age) Sauron could freely change shape and appear however he wished to observers.  This is initially expressed in the *Valaquenta* (in a passage specifically relating to the Valar, but which we may assume also applies to the Maiar):

> Moreover their shape comes of their knowledge of the visible World, rather than of the World itself; and they need it not, save only as we use raiment, and yet we may be naked and suffer no loss of our being ..... But the shapes wherein the Great Ones array themselves are not at all times like to the shapes of the kings and queens of the Children of Ilúvatar; for at times they may clothe themselves in their own thought, made visible in forms of majesty and dread.

And we see an explicit example of him actually doing it in *Of Beren and Lúthien*:

> Therefore he took upon himself the form of a werewolf, and made himself the mightiest that had yet walked the world; and he came forth to win the passage of the bridge.

So it's actually completely incorrect to even speak of 'Sauron in his original "Maiar" form' because this form doesn't even exist.

Comment: So, I should put "his beautiful" form instead ?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it was something they were originally thinking of putting in the movie. I found another copy of that image on the [Annatar page at tolkiengateway.net](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Annatar) along with this accompanying text which is similar to the bit you quoted:

> At an early stage of script development and shooting, Annatar was to
>   be featured in this film. The fair form of Sauron would appear when
>   Aragorn called forth Sauron at the Battle of the Morannon. After
>   blinding everyone, he would change into the black armoured Sauron that
>   appeared in the rest of the film, and battle Aragorn. This idea was
>   scrapped (Aragorn fights a troll instead), but footage was shot, and
>   still exists.[5]

The page cites the source of this as:

> "Michael Pellerin (director), "From Book To Script: Forging The Final
>   Chapter", The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (extended
>   edition), "The Appendices: The War of the Ring"

"The Appendices: The War of the Ring" is one of the extras DVDs that comes on the extended edition of the Lord of the Rings DVD or blu ray set. If you own that, pop it in, select "From Book To Script" on the top menu, then "From Book to Script: Forging The Final Chapter", and the image appears at 10:56 in that featurette.

Comment: It's also possible that Peter Jackson changed his mind about Sauron's physical appearance pre-release, independently of whether or not he chose to include this image or its equivalent in the film.  If he did, the image wouldn't be a movie-canonical image of Sauron.

Comment: @La-comadreja -- isn't anything that failed to be included in the finished movie (theatrical or extended) not "movie-canonical", by definition? Neither the original question nor my answer said anything about canon, the question was just whether the image was "real" (which I took to mean a question about whether the accompanying quote's description of where the image came from was accurate).

Comment: Of course it is a real movie take rather than an internet rumor.  In order to define it as a movie-canonical Sauron image, however, I consider the key question to be whether in the universe that made the final cut (rather than earlier versions of the universe), this would have been an image of Annatar.  I don't see proof either way.  A detail beyond the scope of the question as it is phrased, but one I still want to mention.

Comment: @La-comadreja -- so you think that something can be movie-canonical if there is reason to believe it "would have" made the final cut, even if in fact it didn't? That doesn't really make sense to me--if it's not in the finished movie it can't be deemed movie-canonical, as I said this seems like just a matter of definition.

Comment: it's the same logic that, in book-canon, would make information in Tolkien's letters canonical, but not characteristics of Sauron that appeared in earlier drafts of the work but were changed in the final version.

Comment: @La-comadreja - I see what you mean, though I don't think Tolkien fans would universally agree that things in letters are canon, especially since he sometimes changed his mind. But I think there's a big difference in that the entire world of the books was a product of one man's imagination, whereas movies are collaborative processes, Peter Jackson didn't draw that image of Sauron himself for example, nor was he the sole scriptwriter.

Comment: a movie might be a collaborative process, but someone makes the final approval of every aspect of the universe.  Presumably Jackson.

Comment: @La-comadreja -- sure, but what scenario could justify a belief that they "would have" made the final approval to put it in, if in fact they decided to cut it? Can you give any examples of other movies where you feel that something like this is reasonable?

Comment: A letter from PJ stating that Sauron used to look like so.  A promotional description of Sauron stating he looked this way.  Photographs of "before" and "after" Sauron for fans of the movie.  Etc.

Comment: @La-comadreja -- OK, I was thinking your criteria was whether the scene itself "would have" made the final cut, which doesn't really make sense to me given that it didn't, but it sounds like it was something more like "even though they cut the scene, their reasons for doing so had nothing to do with any change of mind about what Sauron's earlier form looked like." So for example, even in the above cases you wouldn't consider it movie-canon that Sauron manifested in that form in front of Aragorn (as was originally meant to happen in that scene), right?

Comment: Whether Sauron looked like this at any point is one question.  If the answer is yes, this is an image of Sauron.  Whether he looked like this in the Third Age in front of Aragorn is another question, and it seems the moviemakers changed their minds and the answer is no.  So, if the moviemakers changed their minds about the second but not the first, yes this is an image of Sauron, but no it is not a canonical scene.  To use an analogy, is a picture of Sauron visiting the Taj Mahal still a picture of Sauron?  I would say so, but it would also be non-canonical in what he was doing.